# Laravel 5.2 Flash Old and errors empty after redirect

Tags: validation, laravel, session, input, laravel-5

I have a problem in laravel. This problem it's only in production server, in my local server it's work property. So maybe it's something in the configuration that I don't know.

So when I Send a form, with wrong values the laravel validator system should redirect the user to the form and show the errors.

This is the code my controller:

```
$rules = array(
        'nombre'  => 'required|min:3|max:80',
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'asunto'=>'required|min:3|max:200',
        'mensaje'=>'required|min:5|max:1000',
        //'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
         //si la validación falla redirigimos al formulario de registro con los errores
        //y con los campos que nos habia llenado el usuario    
    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('/#contacto')->withErrors($validation->messages())->withInput();
    }
```

/#contacto is the Home route with the anchor contacto so this should redirect to the home. This is ok.

This is my route.php

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('web.index');
});

Route::post('/contacto/enviar', 'WebController@contacto');
```

This is my Kernel

```
 protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],

];
```

This is my view that should show the error result.

```
<form name="contacto" method="post" action="/contacto/enviar"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 wow fadeInUp delay-05s">
                    <div class="form"><font color="#ff0000" size="1"><b>{{$errors->first('nombre', ':message')}}</b></font><input class="input-text" type="text" name="nombre" value="<?=Request::old('nombre', 'Nombre y apellido *');?>" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"><font color="#ff0000" size="1"><b>{{$errors->first('email', ':message')}}</b></font><input class="input-text" type="text" name="email" value="<?=Request::old('email', 'Correo electrónico *');?>" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"><font color="#ff0000" size="1"><b>{{$errors->first('telefono', ':message')}}</b></font><br><input class="input-text" type="text" name="telefono" value="<?=Request::old('telefono', 'Teléfono (incluya código de área) *');?>" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"><font color="#ff0000" size="1"><b>{{$errors->first('asunto', ':message')}}</b></font><input class="input-text" type="text" name="asunto" value="<?=Request::old('asunto', 'Asunto');?>" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"><font color="#ff0000" size="1"><b>{{$errors->first('mensaje', ':message')}}</b></font><textarea class="input-text text-area" cols="0" rows="0" name="mensaje" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"><?=Request::old('mensaje', 'Escriba aquí el mensaje *');?></textarea><font color="#ff0000" size="1"><b>{{$errors->first('g-recaptcha-response', ':message')}}</b></font>{!! Recaptcha::render(['lang'=>'es']) !!}<input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="ENVIAR"></div>
                </div></form>
```

On the top of my view I have a var_dump(Session::all()) and this is the result allways when I submit the form.

```
  array(3) {
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "WrQWk9qTH47QrKD6J0Qld8sOhKcUp8xssGpy0F2g"
  ["_previous"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(25) "http://dsnet.dsnet.com.ar"
  }
  ["flash"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["old"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["new"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

In execution of php artisan route:list this is my result, so I have checked that the web middleware is not duplicate.
[image: This is the print screen of route:list]

The estrange thing is that the same code in my local server is working, and in all the form redirect the result are:

```
array(4) {
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "4s1rhoydlH7l84Em792N79ymemNjh4Ep6I8WLNSG"
  ["errors"]=>
  object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#177 (1) {
    ["bags":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["default"]=>
      object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#178 (2) {
        ["messages":protected]=>
        array(1) {
          ["email"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(40) "The email must be a valid email address."
          }
        }
        ["format":protected]=>
        string(8) ":message"
      }
    }
  }
  ["flash"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["new"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["old"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "errors"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "_old_input"
    }
  }
  ["_old_input"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["_token"]=>
    string(40) "jzCq4CGGgutPJ3qB2ls1rp7uaiHpcra9Aer1vApC"
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(19) "Nombre y apellido *"
    ["email"]=>
    string(21) "Correo electrónico *"
    ["telefono"]=>
    string(38) "Teléfono (incluya código de área) *"
    ["asunto"]=>
    string(6) "Asunto"
    ["mensaje"]=>
    string(26) "Escriba aquí el mensaje *"
    ["g-recaptcha-response"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I remember that I had the same issue in the local server and I fixed setting the domain configuration on the session config file as null, but this solution doesn't work in the production server. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I say that the code it's great! There is not problem with the code, but is a problem with the server configuration. I don't know where. But I upload the site to another server and with the setting of the domain = null, of the session configuration work great.